# Is class faster than CssClass?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm wondering about the performance of:

`<asp:TextBox runat="server" class="someCssClass"></asp:TextBox>`

vs.

`<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="someCssClass"></asp:TextBox>`

My guess is that `class` is faster than `CssClass` because .net probably doesn't do anything with `class`. On the other hand, it has to do some work with `CssClass` to turn it into `class` when it renders.

So really I have a few questions:

- Is there a performance difference?
- If so, is it significant?
- Perhaps the real question should be... If you don't need to refer to the `CssClass` in code, then would it make more sense to just use `class` so you don't make .net do any unnecessary work?

Note: Obviously, there are reasons to use `CssClass` but they are addressed in other questions which we don't need to go into here. However, I didn't find any that addressed performance.

Comment: When you start worrying about performance at an _attribute_ level, you're probably profiling the wrong thing...

Comment: Not that worried about performance as much as I'm wondering if there is any reason to use `CssClass` if I don't need it. It's easy enough to do both so I'm looking for the tie-breaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tiny performance difference, but it is the other way around - I would imagine CssClass could be a bit faster than the `class`.

To understand the reason why it could be so, one needs to have a notion of view state tracking. I would not go into all the details here, but will make a reference to [a classic article about the view state](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate). Please read it, it's awesome!

In short though, ViewState tracking allows some savings for ASP.NET for control properties which are changed from initial values during the page life cycle. `CssClass` is backed up by ViewState, while `Attributes` collection, where `class` goes, most likely is not (I am not 100% certain here, need to check the sources).

As far as rendering goes, there is no likely to be any difference. `CssClass` is translated to html `class` directly, while `class` is being addressed as one of the members of the `Attributes` collection. There is no such thing as direct translation of control markup to html, each of the ways mentioned will result into some amount of rendering processing.